# EXCEL VBA calc sum in list depending on other cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm searching for an way in VBA to sum up values based on another Cell's value

Example Source Table:

```
 BillNr   Pos   Value

  200        0  sum
  200        1  10,00 €
  200        2  15,00 €
  200        3  31,00 €
  200        4  21,00 €
  200        5  19,00 €
  200        6  81,00 €
  201        0  sum
  201        1  14,00 €
  201        2  18,00 €
  212        0  sum
  212        1  31,00 €
  212        2  19,00 €
  212        3  78,00 €
```

Depending on the Number in `BillNr` the VBA Code should sum all Values in `Value` and show that `Number` in the Cell which is called `sum`. In reality the List is something about `15000` rows long so I guess it needs to get wrapped in loop?

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA for this? You can use the `Sumproduct` or `Sumif` formula OR even a `Pivot Table`

Comment: @SiddharthRout: I need to do it via vba because I'm reading this Values in Line by Line from a Text file (via VBA) and everything has to be in a specific format. Also, this Table and the exact positions are the source for another Table....so I'm trapped I guess :)

Comment: Lemme give you an example of both VBA and not Non VBA :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your pick :)

**VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Find "sum" in Col C
        Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:="sum", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell

            '~~> If found Calculate the sum
            aCell.Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUMIF(A:A,A" & aCell.Row & ",C:C)")

            '~~> Find the next "Sum"
            Do While ExitLoop = False
               Set aCell = .Columns(3).FindNext(After:=aCell)

               If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                   If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                   aCell.Value = Application.Evaluate("=SUMIF(A:A,A" & aCell.Row & ",C:C)")
               Else
                   ExitLoop = True
               End If
            Loop
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

***Screenshot***

[image]

**Non VBA (Using Pivot and Vlookup)**

I am using `Vlookup` in Col D after creating the Pivot. You can set `Autofilter` in `Col C` to filter on `sum` and then put the formula in relevant cells in `Col C`

[image]

Comment: ...And that worked out Perfectly (althought I had to mod it a little to fit my needs). Thnak you very much and thumbs up!!